# Cannot install dymo web services

Tags: dymo

I have been trying to install the dymo web services for the last 2 hours on my Windows 10. I have tried everything. I tried regular installation. I tried custom installation selection dymo web service. I cannot locate the **DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe** in my computer. I do have **DYMO.WebApi.Win.Host.exe** on my computer. The app says that the dymo connect service is running on port 41951.

I even have this icon:
[image]

But when i click diagnose I do not see this:

[image]

All I see is this:

[image]

When I go to this

```
https://127.0.0.1:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/Check
```

url to check my print service

I get:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request
>   URI 'https://127.0.0.1:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/Check'. 
>   No route data was found for this
>   request.

Answer (score 2):

a bit late but I just had the same issue. These are the endpoints I have found, according to the latest [js framework](http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/dymo.connect.framework.js), below. You could use https://127.0.0.1:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/StatusConnected to test connectivity.

```
    WS_CMD_STATUS = "StatusConnected",
    WS_CMD_GET_PRINTERS = "GetPrinters",
    WS_CMD_OPEN_LABEL = "OpenLabelFile",
    WS_CMD_PRINT_LABEL = "PrintLabel",
    WS_CMD_PRINT_LABEL2 = "PrintLabel2",
    WS_CMD_RENDER_LABEL = "RenderLabel",
    WS_CMD_LOAD_IMAGE = "LoadImageAsPngBase64",
    WS_CMD_GET_JOB_STATUS = "GetJobStatus";
```

Hope that helps you or someone else. The documentation is *not very good*.